# what are benefits of using ZF2 session than using PHP $_SESSION

Tags: php, zend-framework2

What are benefits of using ZF2 session class and  object than using PHP default $_SESSION array?

Answer (score 4):

Encaplusate and isolate superglobals is a good practice.

Using a container instead of a simple superglobal can allow you to 'mock' the container, if you have to test your application without having to initialize a real session.

And without rewriting your entire code you can choose where your session datas are persisted (filesystem, in memory, in database).